# PowerShell Script to list a server's users, groups, permissions, etc

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a PowerShell script that will query and output all the local and AD users, service accounts, and groups on a given Windows servers. I need the script to recursively list the members of each group that has privileges on that server. I'm looking for a script that will give me a good starting point from which I can tailor it to my specific needs. Thanks.

Comment: This may be of interest to you (even though its not a duplicate): [my answer to "How do you discover what permissions an AD group has, if you have no documentation?"](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/4557/33)

Comment: -1 I voted down as there doesn't appear to have been an attempt by the asker to do this on their own.  I don't believe ServerFault was intended to be a free scripting service.

Comment: @Colyn1337 I'm sorry about that, but I was very new to PowerShell and had a limited time to complete the task. I didn't know where to begin. I'm very grateful for Patrick's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was bored on a lunch break so I made you this.

```
$strLocalMachine = $env:computername

$arrLocalGroups = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Group -filter "Domain = '$strLocalMachine'"
$arrDomainGroups = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Group -filter "Domain = '[YOUR DOMAIN NAME HERE]'"

ECHO ""
ECHO "Local Groups"
ECHO ""

foreach($objLocalGroup in $arrLocalGroups)
{
$groupname = $objLocalGroup.Name

$group = [ADSI]"WinNT://./$groupname"
ECHO "-----$($objLocalGroup.caption)-----"
@($group.Invoke("Members")) | foreach {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}
}


ECHO ""
ECHO "Domain Groups"
ECHO ""


foreach($objDomainGroup in $arrDomainGroups)
{
$groupname = $objDomainGroup.name

$groupmembers = Get-QADGroupMember $groupname
ECHO "-----$groupname-----"
foreach($entry in $groupmembers)
    {
    IF($entry.type -eq 'group')
        {
        Echo "$($entry.name)`n    GROUP MEMBERS"
        $subgroupmembers = Get-QADGroupMember $($entry.name)
        foreach($member in $subgroupmembers){ECHO "    $($member.name)"}
        }
    else{echo "$($entry.name)"}
    $entry = $null
    }
}
```

1. This has a dependency for the [free Quest AD commandlets](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx) to enumerate the domain group memberships. You could amend it to do the same with the Microsoft AD cmdlets if you have installed RSAT or you run this on a DC.
2. I haven't tested this on multiple machines, so can't promise how well it will work beyond my test Win 7 box but this should be ok as long as you are running as domain admin.
3. I feel like the domain groups output is too high for my domain member PC. The command `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Group -filter "Domain = '[YOUR DOMAIN NAME HERE]'"`returned far more than I expected so YMMV, but if they are the correct groups then it should step through and list give you the member ships.
4. I can't work out how to identify if the members of the local groups are a user or Group I'm afraid. The line : `@($group.Invoke("Members")) | foreach {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}` should allow us to invokemember other than name, but I can't get it to work. If someone can clarify that for you you should be able to use that to list members of the local groups.

hope this helps.

Comment: Of course http://poshcode.org/544 this has already been done by someone far more capable than I. I would run his code first and ignore everything I've done!